# How can I devise a leap year to unix time converter?

Tags: c

I made a program to convert an unix time to human date. For instance, if I input a Unix time of 1616580687, the output would be:

18710 days.

year == 2021, month == 3, and day == 24.

hour == 10, minute == 11, and second == 27.

2021-03-24T10:11:27Z

However, when I try to input a leap year, for example 1078012800 in unix time, its output is March 0, 2004 instead of February 29, 2004. How do I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct 
{
int seconds;
} Instant;

typedef struct{
int year, month, day;
} Date;

typedef struct{
int hour, minute, second;
} Time;

bool check_leap(int year){
if(year%400==0||year%4==0&&year%100!=0) 
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

int ifleapyear(int year){
return year/4;
}

int daysAfterEpoch(Instant instant){
return instant.seconds/86400;
}

Date addDaysToEpoch(int days){

Date date;
date.month = 0;

int daysOfMonth[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
int i;

date.year = days / 365;

if(check_leap(date.year))
    daysOfMonth[1] = 29;

date.day = days % 365;
date.day -= ifleapyear(date.year); //subtracts n amount of days of however many leap years have 
passed
date.year += 1970;

for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    if (date.day >= daysOfMonth[i]){
        date.day -= daysOfMonth[i];
        date.month++;
    }   
}
date.month++;

return date;
}


Time calculateTime(Instant instant){

//hour == 10, minute == 11, and second == 27.
Time time;
time.second = instant.seconds % 86400;

time.hour = time.second / 3600;

time.minute = (time.second % 3600) / 60;

time.second = time.second % 60;

return time;
}


void Instant_display(Instant instant){
Date date;
Time time;

date = addDaysToEpoch(daysAfterEpoch(instant));
time = calculateTime(instant);


printf("%i-",date.year);
if(date.month<10)
    printf("0");
printf("%i-",date.month);
if(date.day<10)
    printf("0");
printf("%iT",date.day);
if(time.hour<10)
    printf("0");
printf("%i:",time.hour);
if(time.minute<10)
    printf("0");
printf("%i:",time.minute);
if(time.second<10)
    printf("0");
printf("%iZ",time.second);  
}

int main(){
Instant unixInstant;
Date unixDate;
Time unixTime;
int time;
printf("Unix Time: ");
scanf("%i",&unixInstant.seconds);


time = daysAfterEpoch(unixInstant);
printf("%i days\n",time);

unixDate = addDaysToEpoch(time);
printf("year == %i, month == %i, day == %i\n",unixDate.year,unixDate.month,unixDate.day);

unixTime = calculateTime(unixInstant);
printf("hour == %i, minute == %i, second == %i\n",unixTime.hour,unixTime.minute,unixTime.second);

Instant_display(unixInstant);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with leap years.  It looks like your program misbehaves for the last day of any month.  For example, 1498826096 is a time on June 30, 2017, but the program outputs July 0.

Comment: Hint: what does the test `if (date.day >= daysOfMonth[i])` do on the last day of the month?

Comment: Unrelated: `printf("%02d", 8);` prints "08"

Comment: @SteveSummit im totally bummed out. i had a feeling that this line of code was the issue but i got no clue how to go around it. Thanks!